# jQuery each() not working with click() inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I've created a simple triptych. The issue that i'm having is that when you click on a the first tab of a triptych you see the content of that tab and the content of the the other first tabs. Sorry for including all the JS code, but I had to in order to make it work on the snippet. The issue is inside `$(this).find('.tab').click(function ()});`. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".triptych").each(function () { 
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-icon, .field--name-field-topic-1-title').wrapAll('<div class="iconContainer iconContainer1"> </div>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-2-icon, .field--name-field-topic-2-title').wrapAll('<div class="iconContainer iconContainer2"></div>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-3-icon, .field--name-field-topic-3-title').wrapAll('<div class="iconContainer iconContainer3"></div>');
 
  $(this).find('.iconContainer').wrapAll('<div class="iconsContainer"> </div>');
 
  $(this).find('.iconContainer1').wrap('<a role="button" class="topic1-filter tab" data-tabid="topic1"></a>');
  $(this).find('.iconContainer2').wrap('<a role="button" class="topic2-filter tab" data-tabid="topic2"></a>');
  $(this).find('.iconContainer3').wrap('<a role="button" class="topic3-filter tab" data-tabid="topic3"></a>');
 
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-content, .field--name-field-topic-2-content, .field--name-field-topic-3-content').wrapAll('<div class="tripctychContent-container"></div>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-content, .field--name-field-topic-2-content, .field--name-field-topic-3-content').addClass('hideText');
 
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-content').attr("data-blockid", "topic1");
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-2-content').attr("data-blockid", "topic2");
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-3-content').attr("data-blockid", "topic3");
 
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-content').append('<span class="triangle triangle1"></span>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-2-content').append('<span class="triangle triangle2"></span>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-3-content').append('<span class="triangle triangle3"></span>');
 });

 $('.triptych .iconContainer .field--type-text-long').append('<p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>');

 $(".triptych").each(function () { 
  $(this).find('.tab').click(function () {
  
   var tabID = $(this).data('tabid');
   var isCurrent = !$(this).hasClass('current');
   
   $('.tab').removeClass('current');
   $(this).toggleClass('current', isCurrent);
 
   $('.iconContainerMore').removeClass('hideMoreText');
   $('.iconContainerMore', this).toggleClass('hideMoreText', isCurrent);
 
   $('.tripctychContent-container>div').removeClass('showTopicContent');
   $('.tripctychContent-container').find("[data-blockid=" + tabID + "]").toggleClass('showTopicContent', isCurrent);
  });
  });

  });
```

```css
 .field--name-field-topic-2-content,.field--name-field-topic-3-content,.field--name-field-topic-1-content {
     display: none;
 }

 .showTopicContent {
    display: block;
}

.hideMoreText {
    display: none;
}

.iconsContainer {display: flex;justify-content: space-between;}
p{text-align: center;}
.iconsContainer a {flex: 1; margin-right: 5px;}
.triptych img { width:50px;margin: 0 auto;display: block;height:50px;}
.field--name-field-topic-1-content, .field--name-field-topic-2-content,.field--name-field-topic-3-content{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="triptych">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-icon"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-title field--type-text-long"><p>Topic 1 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-icon"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-title field--type-text-long"><p>Topic 2 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-icon"> <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-title field--type-text-long"><p>Topic 3 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-content"><p>Topic 1 content...</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-content"><p>Topic 2 content...</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-content"><p>Topic 3 content...</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triptych">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-icon"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-title field--type-text-long"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 1 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-icon"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-title field--type-text-long"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 2 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-icon"> <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-title field--type-text-long"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 3 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-content"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 1 content...</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-content"><p> Triptick 2Topic 2 content...</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-content"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 3 content...</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why not remove $(".triptych").each(function () ?, the output is just the same

Comment: @Qonvex620 thanks for checking it out, with or without that function the triptych doesn't work correctly. But I feel like there should be some kind of loop to prevent that issue, which is why i tried using each().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but you want something like this?:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".triptych").each(function () { 
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-icon, .field--name-field-topic-1-title').wrapAll('<div class="iconContainer iconContainer1"> </div>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-2-icon, .field--name-field-topic-2-title').wrapAll('<div class="iconContainer iconContainer2"></div>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-3-icon, .field--name-field-topic-3-title').wrapAll('<div class="iconContainer iconContainer3"></div>');
 
  $(this).find('.iconContainer').wrapAll('<div class="iconsContainer"> </div>');
 
  $(this).find('.iconContainer1').wrap('<a role="button" class="topic1-filter tab" data-tabid="topic1"></a>');
  $(this).find('.iconContainer2').wrap('<a role="button" class="topic2-filter tab" data-tabid="topic2"></a>');
  $(this).find('.iconContainer3').wrap('<a role="button" class="topic3-filter tab" data-tabid="topic3"></a>');
 
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-content, .field--name-field-topic-2-content, .field--name-field-topic-3-content').wrapAll('<div class="tripctychContent-container"></div>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-content, .field--name-field-topic-2-content, .field--name-field-topic-3-content').addClass('hideText');
 
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-content').attr("data-blockid", "topic1");
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-2-content').attr("data-blockid", "topic2");
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-3-content').attr("data-blockid", "topic3");
 
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-1-content').append('<span class="triangle triangle1"></span>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-2-content').append('<span class="triangle triangle2"></span>');
  $(this).find('.field--name-field-topic-3-content').append('<span class="triangle triangle3"></span>');
 });

 $('.triptych .iconContainer .field--type-text-long').append('<p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>');

 $(".triptych").each(function () { 
  $(this).find('.tab').click(function () {
  
   var tabID = $(this).data('tabid');
   var isCurrent = !$(this).hasClass('current');
   
   $('.tab').removeClass('current');
   $(this).toggleClass('current', isCurrent);
 
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.iconContainerMore').removeClass('hideMoreText');
   $('.iconContainerMore', this).toggleClass('hideMoreText', isCurrent);
 
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.tripctychContent-container>div').removeClass('showTopicContent');
   $(this).parent().parent().find("[data-blockid='" + tabID + "']").toggleClass('showTopicContent', isCurrent); // changes
  });
  });

  });
```

```css
 .field--name-field-topic-2-content,.field--name-field-topic-3-content,.field--name-field-topic-1-content {
     display: none;
 }

 .showTopicContent {
    display: block;
}

.hideMoreText {
    display: none;
}

.iconsContainer {display: flex;justify-content: space-between;}
p{text-align: center;}
.iconsContainer a {flex: 1; margin-right: 5px;}
.triptych img { width:50px;margin: 0 auto;display: block;height:50px;}
.field--name-field-topic-1-content, .field--name-field-topic-2-content,.field--name-field-topic-3-content{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="triptych">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-icon"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-title field--type-text-long"><p>Topic 1 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-icon"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-title field--type-text-long"><p>Topic 2 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-icon"> <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-title field--type-text-long"><p>Topic 3 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-content"><p>Topic 1 content...</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-content"><p>Topic 2 content...</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-content"><p>Topic 3 content...</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triptych">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-icon"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-title field--type-text-long"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 1 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-icon"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-title field--type-text-long"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 2 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-icon"> <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300/" ></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-title field--type-text-long"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 3 title</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-content"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 1 content...</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-content"><p> Triptick 2Topic 2 content...</p></div>
            <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-content"><p>Triptick 2 Topic 3 content...</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ritesh! This is very close. Right now if a tab from the top triptych is opened it closes when you click on a tab from the second triptych or vice versa, is there a way to prevent that from happening?